# What are the differences between using vector and using new,delete in c++?

Tags: vector, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator

I would like to ask about the difference between using vector and using new, delete in C++. Both new, delete and malloc, free are used for dynamic memory allocation.

So why don't we just use vector, which automatically allocates memory for us in C++?

Under what circumstances would we need to manually allocate memory using new, delete instead of directly using vector?

I'd appreciate some guidance on this matter. Thank you.

Or perhaps I have misunderstood something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In environments with strict performance and memory constraints, such as embedded systems, manual memory management using new and delete offers precise control over memory allocation. Unlike std::vector, which dynamically adjusts memory size and could potentially exhaust available memory with a simple call to push_back, new and delete provide deterministic memory usage.

Also, this is crucial in time-sensitive applications where every millisecond counts. Another thing, in C-based ecosystems like the Linux kernel and modules, where std::vector isn't available, new and delete remain indispensable for efficient memory utilization. Despite the convenience of std::vector, in contexts demanding tight resource management and optimal performance, the direct control provided by new and delete proves invaluable.

Comment: The Linux kernel is written in C, not C++, so you aren't using `new` either. C is not C++

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was mostly referring to dynamic memory allocation in general.

Answer (score 0):

> So why don't we just use vector, which automatically allocates memory for us in C++?

We do, the vast majority of the time. The small proportion of the time we aren't using `vector`, we are using some other container.

> Under what circumstances would we need to manually allocate memory using new, delete instead of directly using vector?

Never.